# pandas create a new column by comparing two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

df1:

```
ID     Label
1      a
2      b
5      c
```

df2:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

I want to create a new column "label" in df2 by comparing the two dataframes. If the ids match, label in df2 should equal to label in df1. If the id does not occur in df1, I want 0. So the final df2 look like this:

```
ID     Label
1      a
2      b
3      0
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and then replace `NaN`s with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df2['Label'] = df2['ID'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Label']).fillna(0)
print (df2)
   ID Label
0   1     a
1   2     b
2   3     0
```

Comment: No clue about the downvote for the answer and don't care enough to downvote the question, but the question could be answered googling for "merge pandas dataframes" so if I could close a question on laziness I would. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)